# Test installs by Google after submitting to PlayStore?

Tags: android, publishing, screen-size

While Analyzing my App installs vs people actually logging in I noticed several 'ghost' installs of my App. Looks like it happens mainly after publishing a new version, sometimes 5 or 6 in a row, sometimes only 1. Timezone differs, a locale is en-US (i'm promoting in The Netherlands), versions vary from 4.4.2 and upwards, but I am really surprised by the screen size of 288x448?  That can't be a regular phone running Android 4.4 and upwards, right?

Does Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

There are that small phones that are running android 4.4+. Usually rooted phones, but that doesn't matter. Whether it is rooted or not doesn't matter in this case. The point is, there are that small phones with 4.4+, and there are even new models being produced with that small screens.

As for the "ghost installs", if you mean the app is installed and uninstalled right after the update, that's something I have noticed too. It's usually sites trying to get the APK and upload it to their own site. (essentially pirating, but that's a different topic). If that's not what you meant by ghost installs, leave a comment and I'll edit this answer.

And if the APK is available in all countries, it's not surprising you're getting installs from all over the world. There are actual users who wants to try it but end up uninstalling it because it isn't something that user would want on their phone

Comment: I made it available in 18 countries but I was promoting in the Netherlands. The installs I noticed after new installs so you might be right about the piracy. I was wondering whether Google would do some test installs before approving but I guess that is not the case. I use Facebook login, there will be people who blindly install and then Notice they have to login using facebook and decide they don't want that. But it was really the screen size devices I was wondering about. Installing to extract the APK does make sense, I do believe I came across my App in a 3rd party app store.Thank you.

Comment: If you google the package name you can find whether or not its been pirated easily